# boost library in windows Mobile 6.x app

Tags: c++, boost, windows-mobile

Has anyone been able to use Boost in a windows mobile 6.x app? More specifically I want to use [Thunk32](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/thunk32.aspx) for creating a callback to a Non-static Member Function. But it uses some complicated Boost casting methods that will not compile under mobile projects.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile has a crippled implementation of the standard library. You will have to use a more complete version. I personally use [STLPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/). Using that, most of Boost will work fine. I do still have trouble using some of the libraries that are not header-only, though.

Also, that Thunk32 library you pointed to will probably need to be modified for ARM. The assembly code used is x86.

-PaulH

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. I did not even think about the x86 instructions vs ARM. Do you know any other way of creating a callback to a none-static member function?

Comment: windows functions that take a callback typically allow you to pass a user-defined parameter. Try passing `this`. I think you could make that Thunk32 library work if you massaged the assembly, though. I'm no assembly expert, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, some windows API calls do not work that way. for example SetWindowsHookEx does not accept any parameter that I can use and will not pass any value to its callback function.
Like I asked in my original post, Thunk 32 is using Boost to do some sort of casting which I am having hard time to understand.

Comment: @Sam, there's a good reason `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't do that. The callback isn't called by your process, it's called by gwes.exe. Even if you could thunk to it, you'd be dealing with different memory spaces. I have a code project article on this topic, if you're interested: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/WM-Input-Hooks.aspx